# SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Я изучаю Rails и возникла проблема которую я никак не могу решить.

SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

/db/schema.rb:24:in `block in '

schema.rb

```
  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.boolean "correct", default: false
    t.integer "question_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["question_id"], name: "index_answers_on_question_id"
  end

 (строка 24) create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.integer "test_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["test_id"], name: "index_questions_on_test_id"
  end

  create_table "test_passages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "test_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["test_id"], name: "index_test_passages_on_test_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_test_passages_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "tests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.integer "level", default: 0
    t.integer "category_id", null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_tests_on_category_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tests_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "questions", "tests"
  add_foreign_key "test_passages", "tests"
  add_foreign_key "test_passages", "users"
  add_foreign_key "tests", "categories"
  add_foreign_key "tests", "users"
end
```

файл seeds.rb

```
categories = Category.create!([
  { title: 'RUBY' },
  { title: 'HTML' }
  ])
users = User.create!([
  { name: '1User' },
  { name: '2User' }
  ])
tests = Test.create!([
  { level: 1, title: 'RUBY-TEST', category_id: categories.first.id, user_id: users.first.id },
  { level: 2, title: 'HTML-TEST', category_id: categories.last.id, user_id: users.last.id }
  ])
questions = Question.create!([
  { title: 'Вопрос 1', test_id: tests.first.id },
  { title: 'Вопрос 2', test_id: tests.last.id }
  ])
answers = Answer.create!([
  { title: 'Ответ', correct: true, question_id: questions.first.id },
  { title: 'НЕ Ответ', correct: false, question_id: questions.first.id },
  { title: 'НЕ Ответ', correct: false, question_id: questions.first.id },
  { title: 'НЕ Ответ', correct: false, question_id: questions.last.id },
  { title: 'Ответ', correct: true, question_id: questions.last.id },
  { title: 'НЕ Ответ', correct: false, question_id: questions.last.id }
  ])
```

Проверял модели все has_many содержат dependent: :destroy

Краткий стек-трейс

```
Caused by:
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
C:/Users/qytiz/Desktop/rails/TestGuru/db/schema.rb:23:in `block in <main>'
C:/Users/qytiz/Desktop/rails/TestGuru/db/schema.rb:13:in `<main>'
bin/rails:6:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
```

полный стек-трейс

```
Caused by:
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/resultset.rb:170:in `step'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/resultset.rb:170:in `next_hash'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/resultset.rb:105:in `next'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/resultset.rb:133:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:202:in `to_a'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:202:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:151:in `prepare'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:193:in `execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'    
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:24:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:722:in `block (2 levels) in log'C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'  
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'  
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'       
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:721:in `block in log'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:712:in `log'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:23:in `execute'      
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:502:in `drop_table'   
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:312:in `create_table' 
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:890:in `block in method_missing'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:858:in `block in say_with_time'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:858:in `say_with_time'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:879:in `method_missing'
C:/Users/qytiz/Desktop/rails/TestGuru/db/schema.rb:23:in `block in <main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/schema.rb:50:in `instance_eval'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/schema.rb:50:in `define'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/schema.rb:46:in `define'
C:/Users/qytiz/Desktop/rails/TestGuru/db/schema.rb:13:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:328:in `load_schema'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:425:in `block in load_schema_current'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:479:in `block (2 levels) in each_current_configuration'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:476:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:476:in `block in each_current_configuration'    
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:475:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:475:in `each_current_configuration'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:424:in `load_schema_current'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:400:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:404:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'       
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
bin/rails:6:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
```

seeds.rb

```
return if Category.exists?

categories = Category.create!([
  { title: 'RUBY' },
  { title: 'HTML' }
  ])
users = User.create!([
  { name: '1User' },
  { name: '2User' }
  ])
tests = Test.create!([
  { level: 1, title: 'RUBY-TEST', category_id: categories.first.id, user_id: users.first.id },
  { level: 2, title: 'HTML-TEST', category_id: categories.last.id, user_id: users.last.id }
  ])
questions = Question.create!([
  { title: 'Вопрос 1', test_id: tests.first.id },
  { title: 'Вопрос 2', test_id: tests.last.id }
  ])
answers = Answer.create!([
  { title: 'Ответ', correct: true, question_id: questions.first.id },
  { title: 'НЕ Ответ', correct: false, question_id: questions.first.id },
  { title: 'НЕ Ответ', correct: false, question_id: questions.first.id },
  { title: 'НЕ Ответ', correct: false, question_id: questions.last.id },
  { title: 'Ответ', correct: true, question_id: questions.last.id },
  { title: 'НЕ Ответ', correct: false, question_id: questions.last.id }
  ])
```

Все модели:

1.answer.rb

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question

  validates :title, presence: true
  validate :num_of_answers

  scope :correct_only, -> { where(correct: true) }

  private

  def num_of_answers
    errors.add(:question) if question.answers.count >= 4
  end
end
```

2.application_record.rb

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

3.category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { order(title: :asc) }

  has_many :tests, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

4.question.rb

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

5.test_passage.rb

```
class TestPassage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :test
end
```

6.test.rb

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :test_passeges, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passing_users, dependent: :destroy, through: :test_passeges, source: :user

  validates :title, :level, presence: true
  validates :level, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validates :title, uniqueness: { scope: :level, message: 'Идентичный тест уже существует' }

  scope :easy, -> { where(level: (0..1)) }
  scope :medium, -> { where(level: (2..4)) }
  scope :hard, -> { where(level: (5..Float::INFINITY)) }
  scope :from_category, ->(category) { joins(:category).where(categories: { title: category }).order(title: :desc) }

  def self.tests_with_category(category)
    Test.from_category(category).pluck(:title)
  end
end
```

7.user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :test_passeges, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tests, dependent: :destroy, through: :test_passeges

  validates :name, presence: true

  scope :ended_on_level, ->(level) { joins(:test_passeges).where(tests: { level: level }, test_passeges: { user_id: id }) }
end
```

Comment: В какой момент возникает ошибка?

Comment: @Василиса В момент вызова db:setup

Comment: На моменте заполнения сидов? Добавьте к вопросу полный стектрейс ошибки, пожалуйста, и файл seeds.rb

Comment: @Василиса добавил код seeds.rb, моделей и стектрейс , ошибка происходит на моменте добавления сидов к бд

Comment: Безотносительно вашей проблемы - `dependent: :destroy` не нужен на тех связях, которые через `through`. Иначе при удалении теста будут удалены все пользователи, которые его прошли, к примеру

Comment: @Василиса хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Не могу понять, что не так. Проект есть на гитхабе? Если да, киньте ссылкой, я посмотрю

Comment: @Василиса https://github.com/qytiz/TestGuru
Предыдущая версия но проблема в наличии.
Спасибо вам что так стараетесь помочь

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Очень печально было разгребать кучу ошибок в репозитории, чтобы заставить проект работать и добраться до нужной ошибки.
Как у вас вообще на тинкнетике принимают нерабочий код?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполните `rake db:drop` перед сетапом базы. Сетап создаёт базу с нуля и загружает в неё схему.